# Pandas Join not providing the exact results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`. I want to join all columns to `df1` with 2 columns from `df2`.

```
print(df1.shape[0])
# 344
print(df2.shape[0])
# 3577

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2[['latitude', 'longitude', 'code']],
      how ='left', left_on=['LOCATION'], right_on=['code'])

print(df3.shape[0])
# 1740
```

In my output dataframe I need only 344 records from `df1` along with columns from `df2`.

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Why do you assign to `.shape`?

Comment: Duplicates are emerging in your join. There are more than 1 record in df2 that correspond to 1 record in df1

Comment: @FatihAkici, I removed the duplicates from the df2 and did inner join  now I am getting 313 records which 30 less from the df1.

Comment: @DYZ, its a number of records .is that what are you were asking

Comment: @ashokeapen That means you have 344-313 = 31 `LOCATION`s in `df1` that don't exist in the `code`s in `df2`. It's the data's fault, not your code's...

Comment: Why are you assigning to `.shape`!? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, I am not trying assign `'.shape'`. I was just shape explain my case .

Comment: @Aryerez, If that data is not present in Df2. I want assign missing 31 values to null. Can it de done

Comment: If you do `left merge` as in the question instead of `inner merge` as you shifted to in the comments, you will have `Nan`s in the rows who don't exist in `df2`. If you want `Nan` as "null" in a database, replace it to `None`.

Comment: @ashokeapen Oh good, that’s reassuring.

Comment: @Aryerez ‘if you want NaN as “null” in a database, replace it to None’. What do you mean by “null”, or that sentence as a whole, even? Regardless, `NaN` is the standard way to indicate missing data in Pandas.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile He wrote he wants a "null". A "null" is the sql term for unknown value. So I wrote that in order to get a "null" in the database, if he is saving the `df` to sql-server, he will need to replace the "Nan" to `None`, as only `None` is converted to "null" in sql (in sql-server at least). `np.nan` would be saved to the sql database as the string "np.nan".

Comment: @Aryerez When were databases brought up? I might have missed one of OP’s comments.

Answer (score 0):

The second dataframe `(df2)` had dulipicate values which was causing the issue. I removed the duplicate values and joined the `df1` and `df2`. Now it works.

Comment: Were those duplicates unexpected? There are ways of dealing with duplicate data, eh.